Split PDF by bookmark
How can I split a PDF based on bookmark boundaries?
Suppose for example there is a bookmark named "Chapter 1" that points to page 10, and a bookmark named "Chapter 2" that points to page 20.
I want to extract pages 10 to 19 into a file called "Chapter 1.pdf", using the bookmark names (without manually obtaining the pages I want to extract).
Related question on StackOverflow.

You can use pdfextbook to extract bookmarked PDFs on Linux.
It's libre software.
It's available on PyPI, so you can install it with pipx:
pipx install pdfextbook

It uses pdftk to read the bookmarks from the file, fzf to allow the user to select which bookmark to extract, and pdftk again to extract bookmarked pages.
Call pdfextbook with the pdf file you want to extract bookmarks from:
pdfextbook file.pdf

A menu will popup asking you to select which bookmark to extract:

Select the bookmark and it will ask you for the output file name:

Edit the file name as you wish and then press Enter.

Some text explaining HOW to use this tool to solve the problem you presented above in your question would make this an answer. Currently it is closer to a comment. Please EDIT this to make it a complete answer.

Done! (10 more to go)

Much simpler is use any one single cross platform command line tool .
Here using just one exe on windows we see a test source file is a basic 4 KB but when split each file will logically be almost as big, As each needs similar resources. So in many cases not a good idea to split files that have large overlaps in resource usage.
cpdf>dir chapters.pdf|find "."

2024-10-14  16:41             4,269 Chapters.pdf

cpdf>cpdf -list-bookmarks chapters.pdf

0 "Cover" 1 "[1/XYZ 0 845.550161 null]"
0 "Chapter 1" 10 "[10/XYZ 0 841.889771 null]"
0 "Chapter 2" 20 "[20/XYZ 0 845.550161 null]"
0 "Chapter 3" 30 "[30/XYZ 0 845.550161 null]"
0 "Index" 40 "[40/XYZ 0 845.550161 null]"

cpdf>cpdf -split-bookmarks 0 Chapters.pdf -utf8 -o @B.pdf

cpdf>dir cover.pdf "chapter ?.pdf" index.pdf|find "."

2024-10-14  16:51             3,863 Cover.pdf
2024-10-14  16:51             3,919 Chapter 1.pdf
2024-10-14  16:51             3,912 Chapter 2.pdf
2024-10-14  16:51             3,920 Chapter 3.pdf
2024-10-14  16:51             3,742 Index.pdf

cpdf>

You can test what a remerge will be to check the result is not too much overlaps.
cpdf -merge cover.pdf "chapter ?.pdf" index.pdf -o Reclaimed.pdf

cpdf>dir reclaimed.pdf|find "."

2024-10-14  17:01             4,340 Reclaimed.pdf

Thus in this case a very minimal amount of overlapping.

Thank you. cpdf seems a valid alternative. However, the point of this is not to spare disk space. The point is to have a single chapter that I can put inside a USB stick, and the USB stick inside the printer to print it.
